# Am I using these tense correctly?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I saw this in business letter :

1. We **are doing business** with you since **the year 2000** to date.
2. our branch **has sold through** the partner X since its creation more than 10 unites and we are proud **of it** as partner in this business **representing** our brand.
3. I have committed **to observe** the R regulations, **in accordance** with w

All my confused tense and usage in Bold, please kindly answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence where Present Continuous is used is grammatically incorrect, for it indicates a prolonged activity that started in the past and is still going on in present time. Therefore I would say: **We have been doing business with you since the year 2000 to date.**

The second one is correct, for it emphasises the impact of **having sold** a lot of things, etc. However, I would put *since its creation* at the head of the sentence, and after a comma the rest of it could go on.

There's nothing wrong with **of it** because it is the correct preposition to *proud*.

**Representing** as a Gerund form is correct here, too.

Personally, I wouldn't put a comma before **in accordance with**.

Comment: my friend , what about the third one (to observe)

Comment: True. I think it is more likely **I am committed to observe...** because *commit* as a verb can only be used in a meaning like this: *he has not yet committed to any of the candidates* where *commit* expresses the following: *to give someone your love or support in a serious and permanent way*.